# Remove empty headings when converting org-mode to PDF

Tags: pdf, pandoc, org-mode

When converting an org-mode file to PDF with pandoc, how can one configure pandoc to remove all empty headings?

```
* This title should stay
Because there is text here.

* This title should be removed

* This title should be removed too
** Because there is no text content, just another sub-heading also to be removed.

* This title stays
#+BEGIN_SRC
Because of this fine source block.
#+END_SRC
```

This is my pandoc version:

```
$ pandoc -v
pandoc 2.5
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.5.4, texmath 0.11.2.2, skylighting 0.7.7
```

And this is a typical invocation for my use case:

```
$ pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="DejaVu" -V geometry:margin=2cm a.org b.org c.org -o out.pdf
```

Comment: you can write a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)

Comment: Another possibility could be to explicitly put a `:noexport:` tag on the sections headings you don't want exported. The section heading would look like: `* This title should be removed  :noexport:`. Org ignores such sections when exporting.

Comment: @ChrisClark Thank you, that is good to know. It doesn't help here because I can not change the incoming files, but I may use that feature in the future. Thank you.